# OpenGL Heightmap

Tags: opengl, dictionary, height, smoothing

I am working on a project for school and part of it was making a height map.

I managed to create the height map as requested, but was hoping to go for a little extra credit and smooth the entire surface.  Here's an image of what I have now:

http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v222/shavus/hMap.png

The code that I used to generate it was taking an input .jpg and then using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP to create the map that I already have.

The code I used:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
       for(int i = 1; i <= sourceImage->ny; i++)
       {
               for(int j = 1; j <= sourceImage->nx; j++)
               {
                       // Define Color for the Vertex
                       int red = PIC_PIXEL(sourceImage , j, i, 0);                // Find RGB value for each pixel
                       int green = PIC_PIXEL(sourceImage , j, i, 1);
                       int blue = PIC_PIXEL(sourceImage , j, i, 2);
                       float color = (float)(red + green + blue)/(3.0*255.0);

                       // Define Position for the Vertex
                       float xPos = (-1.0 + 2.0*((float)j/(float)sourceImage->nx)) * boxSize;
                       float yPos = (-1.0 + 2.0*((float)i/(float)sourceImage->ny)) * boxSize;
                       float height = (-boxSize + 2*((red + green + blue) / (3.0 * 255.0)));
                       glColor3f(color, color, color);
                       height = height * 0.5 * boxSize;
                       glVertex3f(xPos, yPos, height);
               }
       }
       glEnd();
```

How can I make this a smooth surface to look something more like this?

http://zac-interactive.dk/blogimages/heightmap.jpg

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: The first hyperlink is not working.

Comment: by "smoothing the surface" you mean subdivide the mesh? and what does it look like before smoothing? the normal approach for rendering height maps is to have predefined 2D grid of vertices (e.g. with z = 0) and set the height (in this case z-coord) accordingly to the value computed elsewhere - in the displacement mapping height maps are being created e.g. from diffuse maps converted to gray scale.

Comment: second hyperlink isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to get rid of sudden changes in elevation in your heightmap and thus make it smoother is to run a convolution filter over it.

Here is a link:

http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article2164.asp

on doing the box filter.  It's not the best filter you can use but it will make a big difference.

Comment: There are lots of filters that will drop number of details but will improve "smoothness". And its easy.